# Editing snapped polygons in QGIS: is releasing of snapped vertices possible?

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, snapping, vertices

I have made a layer with polygons that are snapped to each other. Now I would like to edit this layer and create some extra plots in between them.

Is it possible to "unsnap" the vertices? I am using QGIS 2.14.11.

Comment: In `Settings > Snapping Options...`, you can switch snapping off for your current layer and then edit the polygon.

Comment: I have tried this option but it does not seem to work, here is an image of how it looks. [link] (http://imgur.com/a/C2His)

Comment: Could you try on a more recent version of QGIS?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to change the software on this computer. But i have found a solution. I will now use the split object tool (the scissors). It is not ideal but it will work.

Answer (score 3):

As Joseph explained in his comment you can use `settings -> Snapping options` and turn off the snapping of the target layer, as you can see below:

[image]